# Why is it looking like this?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, decompiling, source-code-protection

I am trying to decompile a .swf file so I can read and understand it but when I am decompiling the .swf it looks like this.

[image]

[image]

Have I found the right .swf file or what is the problem?

Comment: What did you use for decompiling? Looks like the original identifiers are not kept in the compiled code, so it came up with random stuff.

Comment: Check this [**explanation here**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/decompiling/info). Better to understand AS3 manual or read tutorials and then ask here for help / clarification.

Comment: Because the author of the code didn't want you to do what you are trying to do and took certain counter-actions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Organis for pointing out the problem:

> "Because the author of the code didn't want you to do what you are trying to do and took certain counter-actions."